# load text from file into listbox

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to load text lines from a text file into a listbox in my form load
I've used this code for this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(sPath);
listBox1.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

but the compiler gives me an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWJMD.png)

Comment: Where is `sPath` declared and what does it contain?

Comment: Also, for information, that is a runtime error, not a compiler error.

Comment: You didn't give string `sPath` value.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is `sPath` is null, wherever you set it, make sure it has a value or the code gets run.

Also please learn to use the debugger to help identify your problems and solutions

[Navigate Code with the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017)